# Are Attribute and Uniform Locations the Same for Different Contexts?

Tags: webgl

If I create two different `WebGLProgram`s from two different `WebGLRenderingContext`s using the same shader sources, will `gl.getAttribLocation`/`gl.getUniformLocation` return the same values for the same attribute/uniform names? That is, if I get the locations from one of the programs, could I use those values when working with the other program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes for Objects (eg. Program Object) in one rendering context should not be used in another rendering context, unless you create a shared rendering context.